# Expected type String, found type str when I explicitly made it String

Tags: rust

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

type Snapshot = HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>;

fn compare_snapshots(snapshot1: Snapshot, snapshot2: Snapshot, entry1: String, entry2: String) {}

fn main() {
    let snapshot1 = HashMap::new();
    let snapshot2 = HashMap::new();

    let entries1: HashSet<String> = snapshot1.keys().cloned().collect();
    let entries2: HashSet<String> = snapshot2.keys().cloned().collect();
    let entries: Vec<String> = entries1.union(&entries2).cloned().collect();

    for e1 in entries {
        for e2 in entries {
            if e1 < e2 {
                compare_snapshots(snapshot1, snapshot2, *e1.to_string(), *e2.to_string());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the following errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:57
   |
18 |                 compare_snapshots(snapshot1, snapshot2, *e1.to_string(), *e2.to_string());
   |                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found str
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `str`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:74
   |
18 |                 compare_snapshots(snapshot1, snapshot2, *e1.to_string(), *e2.to_string());
   |                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found str
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `str`
```

Why did I get them given that I explicitly made gave `entries` a `Vec<String>` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case can be reduced to

```
fn repro(_: String) {}

fn main() {
    repro(*"".to_string());
}
```

For some reason, you are dereferencing the `String`. String implements [`Deref<Target = str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#deref-methods), so you've explicitly attempted to make a `str`. This ultimately won't work because a `str` is unsized, but you are hitting the type mismatch first.

Remove the asterisk:

```
fn repro(_: String) {}

fn main() {
    repro("".to_string());
}
```

See also:

- [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423)

Comment: Thanks, that answers half of the question. Now I need to figure out how to implement the cartesian product in a borrow-friendly manner...

Comment: I read up a bit and iterating over the reference solved the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @d33tah https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.cartesian_product